# How to accept only ordered collections in spec

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, clojure.spec

How can I make a spec that accepts only sequential (i.e. order-preserving) collections?

For example

```
cljs.user=> (s/def ::path (s/+ number?))                                                                                                                                                                                 
:cljs.user/path
cljs.user=> (s/explain ::path [])                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
val: () fails spec: :cljs.user/path predicate: number?,  Insufficient input
:cljs.spec.alpha/spec  :cljs.user/path
:cljs.spec.alpha/value  [] 
cljs.user=> (s/explain ::path [1 2 3])                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Success!
```

That's as expected, but in the same time, pay attention to the order

```
cljs.user=> #{1 2 3}
#{1 3 2}
cljs.user=> (s/explain ::path #{1 2 3})                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Success!
```

And that doesn't appear to make any sense. So a secondary question:

Why sequence-related expressions (cat, *, +, ?) in spec accept sequence-breaking collections?

UPD I've messed up sequential/ordered distinction in original question. Cleaned up terminology.

Comment: `+` means 1..n  (like in a regexp).  It does not imply any order.  You would have to add a predicate for that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specs for sequences (regex specs) should not match ordered, that is *sequential* collections. This was a bug that has been fixed in current versions of spec, see [CLJ-2183](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2183).

In Clojure 1.10.0-RC5 the results are as expected:

```
(s/conform ::path [1 2 3])   ; => [1 2 3]
(s/conform ::path #{1 2 3})  ; => :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid

(s/explain ::path #{1 2 3})
;; #{1 3 2} - failed: (or (nil? %) (sequential? %)) spec: :user/path
```

You can see in the last line that regex specs now only match values that are `sequential?`.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I make a spec that accepts only order-preserving collections?

There's a clojure.core predicate function `sorted?` that will return true for collections that implement `Sorted`.

```
(sorted? (sorted-map))
=> true
```

It doesn't return true for collections with contents that happen to be sorted but don't implement `Sorted`:

```
(sorted? [1 2 3])
=> false
```

You can use arbitrary predicate functions in specs, so you could define a function that returns true for collections with sorted contents:

```
(defn ordered? [coll]
  (or (empty? coll) (apply <= coll)))

(ordered? [1 2 3])
=> true
```

Then you can use `s/and` to combine this predicate with your regex spec:

```
(s/def ::path (s/and (s/+ number?)
                     ordered?))

(s/explain ::path [1 2 3])
Success!
=> nil

(s/explain ::path #{1 2 3})
val: [1 3 2] fails spec: :playground.so/path predicate: ordered?
=> nil
```

Comment: Ordered does not mean sorted …

Comment: I've used bad wording. By ordered I didn't mean sorted, but preserving order.